# pv creation with random name

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I want to create multiple pv with random name instead of giving a static name .Below is my sample yaml to create the pv . Insted of "test-pv" need to create the name as test-pv-some_id or only with some random numbers.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: csi-nfs-sc
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer for the question . instead of metadata name "generateName " will help to create random pv names

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  generateName: test-pv-
```

This will provide an out put like test-pv-fdhhe or test-pv-hhte  some random names at the end.
Note that kubectl apply wont work with generateName , should use kubectl create .